# Php form does not post all fields to MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I checked the answers under ( PHP Form not posting all fields 2  ) and I do have names in all form fields : .... However, It is only posting the id, the date, and the name... I am so confused.

Here is my Sign-up -html-  :

```
<legend>Registration Form</legend><p></p>
<label> Name </label>
<input id="intext"  type="text" name="name" /><p></p> 
<label> Email </label>
<input id="intext"  type="text" name="email" /><p></p>
<label> Zip_Code </label>
<input id="intext"  type="text" name="zipcode" /><p></p>  
<label> UserName </label>
<input id="intext"  type="text" name="user" /><p></p> 
<label> Password </label> 
<input type="password" name="pass" /><p></p> 
<label> Confirm Password </label>
<input type="password" name="cpass" /><p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="center">Comments / Inquiry </div>
<div class="center">
<textarea id="textarea" name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Here is my php function:

```
function NewUser() { $name = $_POST['name'];
$Name       = $_POST['name'];
$Email  = $_POST['email'];
$Zip_Code   = $_POST['zipcode'];
$UserName   = $_POST['user'];
$Password   = $_POST['pass'];
$Comments   = $_POST['comments'];
$query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (Name, Email, Zip_Code, UserName, Password, Comments) 
VALUES  ('$name','$email','$zipcode','$user','$pass','$comments')";
$data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
if($data) { echo "Thank you for Registering with us.";
} 
}
function SignUp() { if(!empty($_POST['user'])) //checking the 'user' name     which is from Sign-Up.html, is it empty or have some text 
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE UserName = '$_POST[user]' AND Password = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) { newuser();
}
```

Comment: By the way you also have issue in your `function SignUp() ` I see extra brackets and they are not closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

In your query are usign variables in lowercase but in variable declarations are with uppercase.

Can you try this code?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (Name, Email, Zip_Code, UserName, Password, Comments) 
VALUES  ('$Name','$Email','$Zipcode','$User','$Pass','$Comments')";
```

Comment: Its not just case, but variable names are a mess, not matching between sections of code.

Comment: well, its a dirty code but sure than the variable names are wrong also maybe that are using a GET method in form tag, but who knows.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. tried Oscargeek’s it worked. Tried Narayan Bhandari returned error at the “echo ‘signup successful’; Narayan suggests (mysqli_* or PDO). any suggestions on where I see an example? --------------------------- { $query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."','".$zipcode."','".$username."','".$password."','".$com‌​ments."')"; if(mysql_query($query,$conn) echo 'signup successful'; // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO else echo 'error inserting new user'; } --------------------------- –

Answer (score 1):

please try this.

I am assuming that you do not have issue implementing $conn, the connection to database, selecting db

sign-up.php

```
<form action="script.php" method="POST">
 <legend>Registration Form</legend> 
 <label> Name </label>
  <input id="intext"  type="text" name="name" /> 
 <label> Email </label>
  <input id="intext"  type="text" name="email" />
 <label> Zip_Code </label>
  <input id="intext"  type="text" name="zipcode" />  
 <label> UserName </label>
  <input id="intext"  type="text" name="user" />
 <label> Password </label> 
  <input type="password" name="pass" /> 
 <label> Confirm Password </label>
  <input type="password" name="cpass" />
 <div class="center"><p>Comments / Inquiry </p>
  <textarea id="textarea" name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
 </div>
</form>
```

script.php

```
<?php
function newUser($conn) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $zipcode   = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $username   = $_POST['user'];
    $password   = $_POST['pass'];
    $password2  = $_POST['cpass'];
    $comments   = $_POST['comments'];
    if($password== $password2)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers VALUES  ('".$name."','".$email."','".$zipcode."','".$username."','".$password."','".$comments."')";
        if(mysql_query($query,$conn))
           echo 'signup successful';
        else
           echo 'error inserting new user';
    }
    else
        echo 'Password missmatched';
}

function signUp($conn) 
{ 
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])) 
    {
        $username   = $_POST['user'];
        $password   = $_POST['pass'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE UserName = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."';";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)<1)
            newUser($conn);
    }
    else
        echo 'form not submitted';
}

// now calling the signUp()

$conn= mysql_connect("","","") or die("Error connecting database"); // host, user, pass to connect db
mysql_select_db(""); // select database

signUp($conn);
?>
```

This is just cleanup of your code. Hope this will help to solve your problem. My implementation would be completely different than this one. 
And one more thing, please use mysqli_* or PDO as mysql_* is depreciated

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. tried Oscargeek’s it worked. Tried Narayan Bhandari returned error at the “echo ‘signup successful’;
Narayan suggests (mysqli_* or PDO). any suggestions on where I see an example?
---------------------------
    {
     $query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers VALUES  ('".$name."','".$email."','".$zipcode."','".$username."','".$password."','".$comments."')";
     if(mysql_query($query,$conn)
     echo 'signup successful'; // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO
     else
     echo 'error inserting new user';
     }
---------------------------

Comment: because at line if(mysql_query($query,$conn) one ')' was missing. it should be working now.